# D exception aborts when called from C++

Tags: c++, exception, d

I export a function from d to c++ with extern(C++). The d code has a try catch statement on the highest level.Whenever the d code throws a exception the program aborts. I have c++ objects on the call stack and call the function in d. Then there is the d try catch statement and then the d exception throw. 
The d code:

```
extern (C++) void ThrowEx() {
    try {
        throw new Exception("hello");
    } catch (Exception ex) {

    }
}
```

The c++ code:

```
extern "C" int rt_init();
void ThrowEx();
void func() {
    rt_init();
    ThrowEx();
}
```

When I change ThrowEx to not throw an exception everything works as expected. The d code gets executed and no error occurs.

When the program crashes the following output is generated:

```
dwarfeh(224) fatal error
uncaught exception
```

Comment: Not knowing D that well, I assume that the `extern (C++)` in D means it will [mangle the name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) `ThrowEx` as the C++ compiler and linker would expect it?

Comment: Yes. Linking works and if I don't throw the exception in d the function will be called.

Comment: You say the program aborts, but does it produce any output at all? Also, is the `catch` in D invoked at all? Could it be that creating the exception object itself already fails, possibly due to faulty integration of D in C++?

Comment: When I only create the exception and do not throw it the program continues. There is a output generated - I edit the question accordingly

Comment: What if you introduce another function that isn't marked as `extern(C++)` as a stack level?  So what if your D try/catch is in a `ThrowExCore()` D function called by `ThrowEx()`?  *(I don't know D either, just wondering if something about extern(c++) in the linker-level might say "oh it's C++...so it must not process any D exceptions)*

Comment: @HostileFork this does not fix the problem.

Comment: Your code works for me, at least dynamically linking the d runtime. What dmd version do you have and what are your compile/link commands?

Comment: It's quite possible that there are bugs. Dwarf EH support is very new.

Comment: From the [D Language Reference](https://dlang.org/spec/cpp_interface.html#exception-handling): *At present, C++ exceptions cannot be caught in or thrown from D, and D exceptions cannot be caught in or thrown from C++.*  Although they have a similar mechanism, C++ and D exceptions are not binary compatible.  You have to fall back to passing an error flag or calling an error handler function.